# Asp.Net Authentication with already existing bearer Token

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, bearer-token

We have a desktop app, which gets a bearer token from our trusted provider by calling a rest endpoint. We also have an asp.net app which should be protected with bearer tokens, there are a lot tutorials explaining how one could configure bearer tokens for a asp.net app. My question is, now I can configure my asp.net app so it accepts an existing bearer token in query string without implementing any login dialogs etc... basically, the goal is to call

http://..../webApp?access_token=#heregoesmyexsitingbearertoken#

and asp.net just takes this token and deserializes it into ClaimsIdentity so I can rely on this Identity in my asp.net code.